# Best way to architect test development in Python so that tests can be run either with a mock or without a mock?

Tags: test-design, python, mock, pytest

I'm starting a fresh `python` project and I want to write unit and integration tests with mocking and stubbing. However, I would like to run these tests during the build-pipeline against actual services by spawning these dependent services in a docker container. What is the best way to architect my project so that I can easily enable and disable mocking so that:

- tests are run with mocks in local branches
- tests are run with actual services (with mocks disabled) in CI build pipeline

I'm using `python3` and `pytest` for my purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create have multiple implementations of your client object.

```
import abc

class MyServiceClient(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def get_item(self, id):
        pass

class MyServiceClientStub(MyServiceClient):
    def get_item(self, id):
        return Item(1)

class RealMyServiceClient(MyServiceClient):
    def get_item(self, id):
        # Make HTTP call
```

If inside your component you program only against *MyServiceClient*, you can inject either a *MyServiceClientStub* or a *RealMyServiceClient* depending on your runtime variables.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found another elegant solution that will work as well depending on your implementation. For my implementation, this worked best.

In your `conftest.py` file where you have your mocking configured, just put it inside an `if/else` condition.

```
# Example conftest.py for your API test
import pytest
import requests

# I'm using this function to define global attributes across all tests
from ..conftest import global_test_attributes
# This is where you have defined your MockResponse Class
from .test_helper import MockResponse


# Any arguments may be passed and mock_get() will always return our
# mocked object, which is defined in test_dataset_get_model_data
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def mock_api_response(monkeypatch):

    """requests.get() mocked to return {'mock_key':'mock_response'}."""

    def mock_get(mock_dataset):
        return MockResponse(mock_dataset)

    # apply the monkeypatch for requests.get to mock_get
    # mocking can be disabled if test attribute is set to "build" mode
    if global_test_attributes()["run_env"] != "build":
        monkeypatch.setattr(requests, "get", mock_get)
        monkeypatch.delattr("requests.sessions.Session.request")
    else:
        pass
```

This is simple and it works